# how to pass an array of struct without pointer? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

hello i am very confused on how to properly pass an array through functions with a struct without using a pointer. we are only supposed to use chapters 1-8 which does not include pointers.. here is my code if anyone has any suggestions or links to help out thank you!

```
const int MAX_DATA = 10000;

struct Inventory
{
   double sku;
   double count;
   double cost;
   string title;
};

void addMovie(Inventory data[], double count);
void allInfo(Inventory data[], double count);

int main ()
{
   Inventory data[MAX_DATA];
   int choice;
   int i = 0;
   double count = 0;
   return 0;
}

void addMovie(Inventory data[], double count)
{
int i = 0;

cout << "Please enter the name of the movie you wish to add " << endl;

cin >> data[i].title;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Please enter the SKU " << endl;
cin >> data[i].sku;
cout << "You have successfully added " << data[i].title << " : " << data[i].sku <<    endl;
i++;
count++;

}


void allInfo(Inventory all[], double count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       cout << "Title: " << all[i].title << endl;
       cout << "SKU: " << all[i].sku << endl;
       i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The proper way would be something like a vector.

Comment: Given the 'chapters 1-8', `std::vector` might not be possible

Comment: @chris Or std::array available in c++11 and onwards.

Comment: Yes, `array` would be better. Personally, the book our school's first C++ course uses has vectors tied in with the chapter on arrays.

Comment: @gamergirl22, I guess you could pass it by reference if you can't use those. Passing it by reference guarantees the size.

Comment: I think you want to make `count` an `int` instead of a `double`.

Comment: @Aleksandar I think ``std::vector`` is better here, since there seems to be no bound to the number of elements that can be added to ``data``.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes A typical C++ course won't mention anything in the STL other than std::string.

Comment: There is no question mark in your post, and you have functions that take arrays.  Can you clarify exactly what the is the issue you're having?

Comment: Exactly what are these chapters 1-8? What book is this?

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about this question, because `[]` _is_ a pointer.  Also, you appear to already have functions that take pointer/arrays, maybe you need to know how to _call_ those functions?

Comment: Voted to close as NARQ. It's impossible to answer the question without knowing the chapters of the book.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know what book you're using, and at least some idea of what you've done (in class?) to handle situations like this already. Right now, any answer is basically a blind guess at what sorts of things chapters 1-8 of your particular book might cover.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a fixed size array, something like this should work, passing the array by reference:

```
template <unsigned long N>
void addMovie(Inventory (&data)[N], unsigned long& count)
{
  std::cout << "addMovie has an array of size " << N << "\n";
}

...

Inventory data[MAX_DATA];
unsigned long counter = 0;
addMovie(data, counter);
```

Note that this gives you will have to make sure not to go beyond the bounds of the array.

It would be way easier to use an `std::vector<Inventory>`, in which case you don't have to worry about the dimensions or the strange passign array by reference syntax:

```
void addMovie(std::vector<Inventory>& data)
{
  std::cout << "addMovie has an array of size " << data.size() << "\n";
  Inventory invent = ....;
  data.push_back(invent)
}

....
std::vector<Inventory> data;
addMovie(data);
```

Comment: If pointers aren't in "chapters 1-8", I don't think templates are.

Comment: @JonathanSeng my advanced C++ book only has 8 chapters :-)

Comment: You are missing the point.  The question is constrained in what can be used and the answer bypasses that entirely and is thus completely useless to the question.

Comment: @Drise and where are these constraints? I didn't see them stated anywhere, except for not using pointers, whatever that may mean.

Comment: @JonathanSeng No, I read the question carefully (admittedly after answering). I think my answer is within the constraints set out in the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you wrap it in a value type, it can be passed directly, or referenced. This is neatly packaged for you in the Standard class `std::array`, but you can write your own struct or class if you want to.

There is no way to pass anything in C++ except by reference, pointer, or value. Thus, as pointers are forbidden, either value or reference *must* be the correct answer. This means that either juan's answer or mine must be correct.

Answer (score 3):

You ask,

> how to properly pass an array through functions with a struct without using a pointer.

I think the key word phrase there is *with a `struct`*.

You can do that as follows, passing *by reference* instead of passing a pointer:

```
#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t
#include <stdlib.h>         // abort
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <utility>          // std::begin, std::end
using namespace std;

typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

template< class Collection >
Size nElements( Collection& c ) { return end( c ) - begin( c ); }

wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, string const& s )
{
    return (stream << s.c_str());
}

void error( string const& message )
{
    wcerr << "!" << message << endl;
    abort();
}

struct Person
{
    string      name;
    int         birthYear;
};

struct Persons
{
    int         count;
    Person      data[10000];
};

void addTo( Persons& persons, string const& name, int const birthYear )
{
    if( persons.count == nElements( persons.data ) )
    {
        error( "Max capacity exceeded." );
    }

    Person& person = persons.data[persons.count];

    person.name = name;
    person.birthYear = birthYear;

    ++persons.count;
}

int main()
{
    Persons     persons = {};       // All zeroed out.

    addTo( persons, "Maria", 1990 );
    addTo( persons, "Eliza", 1965 );

    assert( persons.count == 2 );

    for( int i = 0;  i < persons.count;  ++i )
    {
        wcout
            << i << ": " << persons.data[i].name
            << " born " << persons.data[i].birthYear
            << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that this code only illustrates how to do what you apparently ask for, a learning exercise thing.

For real code, use e.g. a `std::vector` instead of a fixed size array.

Answer (score -3):

`void addMovie(Inventory data[], double count)` should be fine.

The `[]` means that `data` is a pointer in disguise.  `data` can be dereferenced as `*data` to get the first value in the array, just the same as getting it by index as `data[0]`.

The only difference between `Inventory data[]` and `Inventory* data` is you are telling the reader of the code that you mean a continuous array of allocated objects (which, by the way, could be of size 0, 1, or any other integer within limits of the memory).

The compiler and runtime won't distinguish between the two.  Calling the array method as `addMovie(0x0, 0)` will work just the same as the pointer version.

Additionally, since you attempt to update `count` in the method, you might wish to take it by reference `double &count` and you might also wish to use an integer if the count is of whole items not partial values `int& count.`

Comment: The type of the second parameter should not be `double`.  It should be an `int&`.

Comment: That is a separate issue, but edited in.

Comment: "but its not quite the same" It's exactly the same.

Comment: Edited.  Yes, to the compiler the two are exactly the same.  However, the notation exists to disguise the evil pointer, but also to make a completely unenforced claim that this is an array pointed to, not a single value.